# NodeJS Sequelize throw new errors.AssertionError({ error connection

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, sequelize.js

I'm trying to connect to a postgre(heroku) with the sequelize.
But the sequelize returns an error when starting my application

Help me us.

Error message returned when you run the command "*node app.js*":

```
$ node app.js
assert.js:42
  throw new errors.AssertionError({
  ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: false == true
    at Object.exports.connect (_tls_wrap.js:1036:3)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\DaniloNote\Pessoal\Projetos-Testes\Node8AndSequelize\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:94:23)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:607:20)
```

My file package.json

```
   {
  "name": "teste",
  "description": "teste",
  "author": "danilo <danilovex@gmail.com>",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.11.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "pg": "^7.4.2",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.2",
    "sequelize": "^4.37.7"
  }
}
```

My file app.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  host: 'host',
  dialect: 'postgres',
    dialectOptions: {
                  ssl: true
              },
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  }
});

sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });
```

This error happened when I updated my package to version 8 of the node.

Tks.

Comment: It's because of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50203747/error-connecting-to-heroku-postgress-db-in-nodejs

Comment: @vitaly-t, the problem was the pg module version. Thank you so much